# Resources for kids education

Tags: reference-request, education

Most of the questions on MSE about educational resources are for high school. At least I haven't found questions which deals with sites on very elementary mathematics.

I will be grateful if someone provides me with list of educational resources for kids - e.g. of the level of kindergarten, primary school and junior high school.

If you think that this question is not for MSE, tell me were is it appropriate to ask?

Comment: This question seems to be somewhat related: [Interesting math books for children](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68851/interesting-math-books-for-children). And maybe this one too: [Fun math for young, bored kids?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69002/fun-math-for-young-bored-kids).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some things I found in a few minutes. I'm also including what seemed to be the best google search among those I tried.

Google search for [“elementary school” mathematics resources links](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22elementary%20school%22%20mathematics%20resources%20links&gws_rd=ssl)

[Math Archives: K-12 Teaching Materials](https://web.archive.org/web/20220120120512/http://archives.math.utk.edu/k12.html)

[Awesome Library: Elementary School Math](https://www.awesomelibrary.org/Classroom/Mathematics/Elementary_School_Math/Elementary_School_Math.html)

[Ask Dr. Math: Elementary Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20171223110038/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/drmath.elem.html)

[Ask Dr. Math: Middle School Archive](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/drmath.middle.html)

[edHelper.com: Math Worksheets and Math Printables](https://www.edhelper.com/math.htm)

[FunBrain.com’s collection of math games](https://www.funbrain.com/pre-k-and-k-playground)

Answer (score 3):

Though not a direct answer to your question, another resource you may be able to use is a university sponsored Math Circle program. They really are amazing and I am extremely jealous of those kids (I wish I got to go to a Math Circle when I was their age!). If you're not familiar with what it is, it's basically a program where your kids can go and learn mathematics they wouldn't normally be exposed to in school, with peers of their age.

To give you an example, at UCLA (where I attend) the fifth grade age group learned basic abstract algebra, cryptography, and fundamentals of proofs.

Check your local schools out! [Math Circle Main Website](http://www.themathcircle.org/)

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

WGBH has launched an all-new bilingual [Web site](http://peepandthebigwideworld.com/en/) and curriculum for PEEP and the Big Wide World, the Emmy Award-winning preschool science and math series for 3-5 year olds.

TenMarks Education has a professional development, preparatory, and in-class resource for teachers. The program focuses on grades 2-6, with instructional resources for 12 core standards available at no cost to educators. It's called [TenMarks Math Teach](https://www.tenmarks.com/math-teach-how-it-works).
[Glean](https://glean.co/) - An excellent site for fiding educational videos and lessons on math and science.

Answer (score 0):

For Kindergarten and elementary school you should check out [ClassK12](http://www.classk12.com) 
which comprehensively covers the curriculum in a fun interactive format.